# iOS: how to respond to up/down/left/right arrow event from physical keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, keyboard

By physical keyboard I mean the bluetooth wireless keyboard connecting to the iOS device, or the iPad keyboard Dock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no officially sanctioned way to do this.  The best you can do is override -[UIApplication sendEvent:] and take a look at the events coming through.